# How can I stream audio from the microphone of an iPhone to a Mac/PC via sockets or a framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, audio, streaming

How can I stream audio from the microphone of an iPhone to a Mac/PC? Is there already some framework for this, or can I just send audio over sockets. I'm new to sockets though. Basically, I want to be able to speak into the iPhone, and the computer will receive the iPhone's mic input as its own mic input for computers that do not have microphones. I already have an app that makes a bonjour connection to a Mac, which runs a very simple server, and the iPhone can send text to the computer, but how could the iPhone send audio, live audio from the mic, to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a combination of AVCaptureSession and AVCaptureDevice to read from the microphone - see the AV Foundation Programming Guide.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVCaptureAudioDataOutput

For link to use sokets

```
@interface Client : NSObject {
    NSInputStream *_inputStream;
    NSOutputStream *_outputStream;
}

@implementation Client

- (void)initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"localhost", 50000, &readStream, &writeStream);

    _inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    _outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [_inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [_outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [_outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [_inputStream open];
    [_outputStream open];
}

// send data to server


- (IBAction)onSendButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    NSString *command = self.commandField.text;
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[command dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [_outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];
}
```